# Bad magic number error with ZipFile module in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, unzip, python-zipfile

I am using Python 2.7 on Windows 7 (64 bit).
When I try to unzip a zip file with ZipFile module I get the following error:-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "unzip.py", line 8, in <module>
    z.extract(name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\zipfile.py", line 950, in extract
    return self._extract_member(member, path, pwd)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\zipfile.py", line 993, in _extract_member
    source = self.open(member, pwd=pwd)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\zipfile.py", line 897, in open
    raise BadZipfile, "Bad magic number for file header"
zipfile.BadZipfile: Bad magic number for file header
```

WinRAR could extract the file I am trying to extract just fine.
Here is the code I used to extract files from `myzip.zip`

```
from zipfile import ZipFile
z = ZipFile('myzip.zip')   //myzip.zip contains just one file, a password protected pdf        
for name in z.namelist():
    z.extract(name)
```

This code is working fine for many other zip files I created using WinRAR but `myzip.zip`

I tried commenting the following lines in `Python27\Lib\zipfile.py`:-

```
if fheader[0:4] != stringFileHeader:
   raise BadZipfile, "Bad magic number for file header"
```

But this didn't really help. Running my code with this in effect, I get some dump on my shell.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Correct ZIP files always have "\x50\x4B\x03\x04" in the beginning. You can test whether file is really ZIP file with this code:

```
with open('/path/to/file', 'rb') as MyZip:
  print(MyZip.read(4))
```

It will print header of file so you can check.

**UPDATE**
Strange, testzip() and all other functions work good. Had you tried such code?

```
with zipfile.GzipFile('/path/to/file') as Zip:
  for ZipMember in Zip.infolist():
    Zip.extract(ZipMember, path='/dir/where/to/extract', pwd='your-password')
```

Comment: @petr-viktorin Yes, it's a zip. The above code gave `PK♥♦` as output.

Comment: Hm. Could you put your file on any server so I can look at it and try to open it?

Comment: Look at the original answer, I've posted another idea.

Comment: Hm, I can't extract pdf from your file using Ark. To be more correct, it extracts empty file which has size 0 KiB.

Comment: 7-Zip says "Unsupported compression method"

Comment: Python's zipfile currently supports only DEFLATE method. It seems you've created your file with WinRar using another method, so zipfile can only read file, but not extract.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you are really opening a ZIP file, not for example a RAR file named with a .zip extension. Proper zip files have a header, which was not found in this case.

The `zipfile` module can only open zip files. WinRAR can also open other formats, and it likely ignores the filename and only looks at the file itself.