# Extracting .zip in python

Tags: python, jar, unzip, zip

I got `BadZipfile: Bad magic number for file header` error while extracting a .zip using python2 `zipfile.ZipFile`

Same .zip when extracted with unzip gives `file #1:  bad zipfile offset (local header sig):  0` but gets extracted with exit code 2.

When using `jar -xf file.zip` the command completes with `$? == 0` with nothing being extracted.

Using file gives:

```
file -i file.zip
file.zip application/octet-stream; charset=binary
```

This gives incorrect header for zipfile

```
$ hexdump -C file.zip | head -10
00000000  50 67 f0 de 1e 7a 29 e4  93 56 3f 11 a2 5f b6 97  |Pg...z)..V?.._..|
```

Correct header is:

```
00000000  50 4b 03 04 14 00 08 08  08 00 28 3e 4b 4b 00 00  |PK........(>KK..|
```

Why is the file listed as application/octet-stream ?

I am on

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
```

Whats going on ? What file format is this ? Any pointers ?

Comment: have you tried all other ways: `gzip`, `unzip` ?

Comment: maybe archive is corrupted?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bad magic number error with ZipFile module in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7703639/bad-magic-number-error-with-zipfile-module-in-python)

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest With unzip I get exit code 2 but the file gets extracted.

Comment: `file -i file.zip` gives application/octet-stream. Why ?

Comment: I added few extra details from hexdump. Which file format is this ?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this?

```
import zipfile
zip_ref = zipfile.ZipFile(path_to_zip_file, 'r')
zip_ref.extractall(directory_to_extract_to)
zip_ref.close()
```

Comment: Then may be this could help [https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/3149/zipfile.BadZipfile]